# Trouble trying to print string in order from a tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

I want to turn a tree into a string and get prestr order (starts with root and goes down all left nodes then to the right ones back up) example: tree (root (left (a) (b)) (right (c) (d))) would be "root left a b right c d".

```
class TreeNode:
def __init__(self, data = None):
    self.data = data
    self.children = []

class Tree:
def __init__(self, string = None):
    self.root = None

def prestr(self):
    string1 = ""
    value = self.root
    string1 += value.data
    string1 += " "
    while len(value.children) > 0:
        for i in value.children:
            string1 += i.data
            string1 += " "
            value = i
    print(string1)
```

This when running this code with

```
tree (root (left (a) (b)) (right (c) (d)))
```

I get: `"root left right c d"`. I suspect this is becasue it doesn't run `for i in value.children` on `value.children[0]` when that is set as the value but I don't know why. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you set `value = i` in the for loop. When you do this, you expect your code to go back to `while ...:` but it *doesn't*, instead it goes to the next iteration of the for loop. The result of this is that you set value to the *last child of the node* in the for loop before actually continuing on that value. This skips all but the last child of each node, which is why you were seeing the behaviour you were. In order to keep as close to your original solution while being correct, I would suggest using recursion for this code instead, as it is much easier to reason about in this case:

```
def prestr_helper(value):
    if len(value.children) > 0:
        return value.data + ' ' + \
            ' '.join(prestr_helper(child) for child in value.children)
    else:
        return value.data

def prestr(self):
    print(prestr_helper(self.root))
```

However, this does have the problem of Python's recursion limit and so will fail at trees of depth 1000 or more (approximately). In order to circumvent this restriction you would have to implement an iterative solution such as one described [here](http://algorithmsandme.in/2015/03/preorder-traversal-of-tree-without-recursion/).